# How can I improve API response speed if it uses CloudFlare

Tags: python, websocket, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I need the fastest API response from exchange to find arbitrage opportunities as quickly as it possible. Now I am using WebSocket connection to the API, but speed is still not enough good. Tried all server locations, that are available in AWS, but this does not change situation much. In my opinion the problem is about CloudFlare. Does someone know about how to bypass its limitation?

Comment: Are you sure it's just not your upstream service that's not fast enough? Secondly, why do you need Cloudflare?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Argo Smart Routing service](https://www.cloudflare.com/products/argo-smart-routing/)? It is specifically aimed at highly dynamic content (as in, not cacheable) and it aims to improve the performance of the traffic between the Cloudflare datacenter and your origin server.